# Dialogflow messing up money on voice to text

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have an agent that can recognize sentences like:

Today I spend 10 dollars on Starbucks
or
Today I spend 10 reais ( Brazilian money ) on coffee.

In those example sentences, I can recognize 10 dollars or 10 reais as System Entities of @sys.unit-currency and everything is fine.

The problem is when I try to input data as voice Dialogflow will automatically convert my text to:

Today I Spend $10 on Starbucks

And for some reason, the agent will not recognize $10 as @sys.unit-currency

I tried to train the agent if the new inputs but he just wont work, any ideas?

Comment: Are you using any integrations, or just Dialogflow directly?

Have you tried providing a training phrase for both forms "10 dollars" and "$10" in the intent?

Comment: Just dialogflow directly, I have tried to teach the agent to understand both "10 dollars" and "$10" unfortunatly i was unable.

Comment: Have you tried "$ 10" with a space inbetween? I'm thinking it thinks $10 is some kind of variable name of the form $x

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something has changed on the Dialogflow side since this question was posted, but I have just tested this myself and the agent identified the intent and all its entities correctly, recognizing the [`@sys.unit-currency` system entity](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities#amounts_with_units) as expected.

This is my single training phrase, where "$2" is of type `@sys.unit-currency`:

[image]

And when testing with queries including prices of the type "$5" or "5 dollars", the entity is matched under all conditions:

[image]

Additionally, it is true what @TaylorCaldwell mentioned in his comment, about Dialogflow sometimes not recognizing properly symbols combined with words, but in this case I have had no issue to build the training phrase I shared.